# Chromium build (gclient)

Tags: git, build, chromium, git-for-windows, gclient

I'm trying to build chromium on my external drive, because I don't have enough space on my computer. I do everything in accordance with the instructions: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

The following errors appear during the run of the `gclient` command:

```
D:\>gclient
error: could not write config file D:/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_20_bin/git/etc/gitconfig: File exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 356, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 321, in main
    git_postprocess(template, os.path.join(bootstrap_dir, 'git'))
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 289, in git_postprocess
    call_if_outdated(
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 138, in call_if_outdated
    fn()
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 282, in configure_git_system
    _check_call([git_bat_path, 'config', '--system', 'core.autocrlf', 'false'])
  File "D:\depot_tools\bootstrap\bootstrap.py", line 196, in _check_call
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, argv, None)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\depot_tools\\git.bat', 'config', '--system', 'core.autocrlf', 'false']' returned non-zero exit status 4.
```

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: The fact that it can't write to the config file is what's preventing progress. Why it *wants* to write there, and *why it can't*, are both mysteries to me.

Comment: For me too( I am running as administrator and the problem does not change